# ngResource default parameters from promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-resource

I have several rest services that looks like this

```
/user/:userId/resource/:resourceId
```

Most of the time the user wants to get his own resources (although sometimes he wants to get anther user's resource)
so I want the default parameter to be the current user Id but I cannot save the UserId on a rootscope/service because if the user refreshes the browser this will be gone, so I want to do something like this:

```
$resource('/user/:userId/resource/:resourceId', { userId: getUserId, resourceId: '@id' })
```

the problem is that the `getUserId()` returns a promise:

```
function getUserId() {
    if (!$rootScope['user']) {
        $rootScope['user'] = UserService.get({ userId: 'current' })
    }
    return $rootScope['user'].$promise.then(function (user) {
        return user.id;
    }
}
```

how can I make it work for all services (as for now I'm just always chaining every resource service after the userId getter... is there a better way?

Comment: Personally, I store non-sensitive data like this in the session. That way it is readily accessible and available until the browser is closed or the user logs off. It is much easier than trying to set up services to handle something like this.

Comment: If it was a regular $http call it would have been pretty easy, with a resource its more work because of a resource's behavior. I can help you if you change that $resource to a regular $http call and you can adapt it from there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I know it is possible to manually build such a request, but I have many restful apis and the ngResource library serves me pretty well.

Comment: Well, you can always put a promise for the userId in the `resolve` clause of the router.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Nice, I never used the "resolve" feature yet, seems useful, thanks. But now everyone promotes not using controllers with routes directly and go through directives instead, and passing another general variable to every directive is cumbersome. Seems like I can hook up local storage to the request directly and I can forget about finding where to get the userid from. Do you know of a way to do something similar to the resolve feature? Waiting for promises to resolve syncroniclly? Because if it can be done I could hook that up instead of passing through the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the browser session to store this non-sensitive data.

```
// Set the user object into the session as a JSON object
function setUser(user) {
    sessionStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
}

// Retrieve user object and parse the userID
function getUserId() {
    var tmpUser = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
    return tmpUser.userID;
}
```

Then your $resource will not have any promises being returned to it and you can access/modify the userID from anywhere in the code without polluting your $rootScope.